# How to make links open in email clients?

Tags: html, wordpress, email, hyperlink, contact-form-7

I'm trying to make a custom email template that is sent to a user once they fill out a form on our site. At the bottom of the email we want a button that links to a page on our website. So far I've tried using the a, button, and form tags and all of these work when you use gmail and are already in the browser but if you use outlook, the apple mail app, or any others, the button appears to click but doesn't actually do anything. Is there any sort of workaround for this? Am I just missing something simple?

Thank you so much for any help! This has been driving me crazy all day.

Comment: Include what you have written please. You need HTML email in order to include html elements in your email. Your code ....please

Comment: <form action="www.google.com">
    <input type="submit" value="Link to google.com">
</form> is what I had tried for form. I was just using <a href="google.com">Link to google</a> for the link. (not sure how best to format this, I'm pretty new to this site, haven't ever posted before). When I tried as a button is used <button onclick="window.location.href='www.google.com'" type="button" style="background-color:#0184DD; color:#FFFFFF; align: center">Link to google</button>

Comment: Welcome,  please follow http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.   Also, how do you send your email? using php? Any framework

Comment: Thank you, I'll read over that page in just a second here. We're using a wordpress site and using a plugin called Contact Form 7 to send the email. There's an option that says "use HTML content type" but it's selected and all the other html and css works perfectly fine, it's just that when using outlook or another email client when you click on the link it does nothing when we need it to open the browser and go to that url.

Comment: did you include the protocol in the link href? (http://)